# Link Aggregation between DELL PC2724 and Cisco Catalyst 3750

Tags: cisco, dell, switch, lag, lacp

I'm trying to configure Link Aggregation between my two switches, on the DELL switch, there is only an option to include a port in a "LAG Group." On the Cisco's I've tried creating an EtherChannel group with "Dynamic Desirable" (set to negotiate). I have also tried to setup the ports as 802.11Q as well as ISL Link (both with same results)

When I plug in the cables, I can see that the links come up for each individual port, but the trunk does not.

I can see the status of each individual "port" on the Cisco as well as the EtherChannel group from the Cisco and each of the individual ports show status "stand-alone."

The lights on the Cisco switches start orange (normal) and eventually go to green, but I cannot get any traffic across the cross-connect. If I remove all "configuration" and use a single cable, everything works fine. I'm trying to get some additional speed with the LAG.

Any thoughts on what I should try?

Comment: are you running a fairly recent firmware on the Dell? you should create a lag first, then enable LACP on the links in the LAG. set the other side accordingly

Comment: No... What version have you seen this work on?

Comment: Can you post the port configuration on both switches? channel-group mode desirable is using PaGP, not LACP.

Comment: That maybe my problem... I know the Cisco supports LACP, but as far as I can tell, the DELL switch does not support anything other than "LAG" which I understand to be an encompasing term for link aggregation, not a specific type. I'm still hunting down new firmware to see if it provides more options for what type of LAG to form. Should I be using 802.11Q on the Ciscos though?

Comment: I'm running 1.0.1.07 firmware on the DELL. I should also mention, I have other EtherChannel ports working with other (newer) DELL switches.

Comment: After some research, that is the most up to date Firmware available for this DELL switch.

Answer (score 1):

http://accessories.dell.com/sna/PopupProductDetail.aspx?sku=P2741NP says that it supports LACP, so that's what we should try go with.  I would set the config on the cisco:

```
int g1/1
channel-group 1 mode active
```

and then int-portchannel 1 and set your trunking there - but let's get the LACP working first.

Comment: I have a Stack of Ciscos, I'm trying to do the trunk across g1/0/11 and g2/0/11 -- what would the configuration look like for that? I setup an etherchannel for those two ports, and as stated, eventually the Link Light goes to green, but no traffic flows.

Comment: well, I never actually see the lights, but:  int g1/0/11; channel-group 1 mode active; int g2/0/11; channel-group 1 mode active; int port-channel 1, and then show channel-group 1 detail on the cisco